# Xilinx FPGA output to output timing constraints

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I have a Spartan-6/ISE design where I'm generating 8-bit data @ 70MHz to feed the FIFO of a Cypress FX3 USB3 controller. I also generate a 70MHz o/p clock and /WR strobe that clock data into the USB controller. The 70MHz is derived from halving the 140MHz system clock, divided by 2 in a process rather than using a DPLL, though the 140MHz system clock is produced using a DPLL.

I want to ensure the 8-bit data meets the set-up & hold time requirements of the USB controller and, although the data, o/p clock and /WR are derived from the 140MHz, I don't really care about their relationship to it. What I'm really concerned about is ensuring the set-up & hold times for data & /WR w.r.t the 70MHz o/p clock are within the USB controller limits.

My question is: how do I go about specifying timing constraints between FPGA outputs rather than w.r.t. to the internal system clock ?

Thanks
Dave